# Prevent overwrite when refreshing pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I have a macro that updates a pivot table weekly that expands the table to new columns.  Other users have created notes in the columns to the right of the pivot table that I would like to preserve.  Upon refreshing the table, I get an alert that "There's already data in XXXX. Do you want to replace it?"

Is there a way to detect whether pointing the table to a new source will cause an alert and automatically cancel it?  I can't just set

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

because this would ignore the warning and overwrite the notes.  I tried the following, but the alert interrupt prevents execution of the next line.

```
Set pvtTbl = reconWB.Worksheets("PIVOT_ALL").PivotTables("PIVOT_ALL")
On Error Resume Next
pvtTbl.SourceData = rawData     'Updates pivot and causes the "There's already data..." alert if there are notes
SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"             'My attempt to close the alert window, but the alert interupt prevents further execution

'The following works, if I select "Cancel" and close the alert
Do While Err <> 0
    reconWB.Worksheets("PIVOT_ALL").Columns(pvtTbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count + 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Err = 0
    pvtTbl.SourceData = rawData
    SendKeys "{ESCAPE}"
Loop
On Error GoTo 0
pvtTbl.RefreshTable
```

I hate messing with the error handling, but I couldn't think of another way to do it.  Not that what I tried works!  Thank you for looking!